# SharePoint Graph API Retrieve Document id using Document url

Tags: graph, sharepoint-online

Try to retrieve a document id from the document URL from SharePoint online specific library.
I need the id to be able to get the content of this document in xml format.

Can find the right command to in MSGraph to get the document id from the document URL.